# Oracle apex 5: New computations added to page throw ERR-1002

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

In a page that was created a while back, everytime i add a new computation (give it some name) i get this error:

ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "PROBA" in application "810".

Unexpected error, unable to find item name at application or page level.

```
Technical Info (only visible for developers)
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: WWV_FLOW.FIND_ITEM_ID_ERR
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_COMP
component.id: 79749128835570313
component.name: PROBA
error_backtrace:

----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
000007FFFC131638       641  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
000007FFFC131638       709  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
000007FFFC131638      1013  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
000007FFFC2CDD00      2994  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_META_DATA
000007FFFC239CE0      1731  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_SESSION_STATE
000007FFFC160470        51  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_COMPUTATION
000007FFFC160470        98  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_COMPUTATION
000007FFFC160470       238  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_COMPUTATION
000007FFFC4566D8      4864  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW
000007FFFC4566D8      4914  package body APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW
000007FFFC351EC8       173  procedure APEX_050000.F
000007FFFC344EA0         2  anonymous block
```

Any help on why this is happening?

Comment: message is clear, there is a component named ID is missing.

Comment: for every single new computation i make on that page is says the same. I think "item ID" means that items identification and not that an item called ID is missing on that page.

Comment: Even when i copy an existing computation and rename it i get the same error message. ex. computation LAST_PAGE. make a copy, name it LAST_PAGE1 i get:
ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "LAST_PAGE1" in application "810".

Comment: well, can you paste the query of computation and the page item name

Comment: There is no query. The computation item name is "LAST_PAGE", Type is "Static value" and the value is 11. Like i said. It throws this error for any and every new computation i add.

Comment: what is the point of execution (i.e before regions, ...) if it is before region then the item at this point is not rendered then it will throw an error, try to make the point after region or at any point after.

Comment: All the computations on my page are in the same place, that is in the Pre-Rendering / Before Header / Computations.

Comment: then I think the error is from another component as in your info
the error from component named 'PROBA'

Comment: Read the original question, please. The error is thrown for every and any new computation i add to the page. "PROBA" was just the name given to the computation at the time i posted the question which threw the error, and the stack i posted was from that particular error. It was one example! Later i said that even when i copy an existing computation and give it a new name it throws an error (a few messages back)....

Comment: Is there anything "special" about eg item `LAST_PAGE`? Is this a page item, an application item?

Comment: No, nothing special. It is a computation created on the page. The problem is the error "ERR-1002" is thrown for any new computation i create on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computations are done on ITEMS (either page or application ITEMS). What this error says is that you are missing the ITEM called "PROBA". Check the page or application items and see if that item exists.

Comment: I was indeed missing the item "PROBA"

Answer (score 1):

The item name that can't be found is "PROBA".

You can query the APEX data dictionary for the source of the error.  If you do a query in SQL Commands of:

```
select * from apex_application_page_comp 
 where application_id = 810 
   and computation_id = 79749128835570313
```

You'll find the source of the problematic computation.

Comment: PROBA810BEFORE_BOX_BODYSTATIC_ASSIGNMENT1Not found

This is one of the columns that the query returns. I tried googling it, but found nothing.

Comment: I was indeed missing the ITEM.